# JUnit Local Test - 'Unresolved reference: test'

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, junit4, android-testing

## Expected

Importing libraries such as `androidx.test:core:1.2.0`, `androidx.test.ext:truth:1.2.0`, `com.google.truth:truth:0.44`, and etc. into a **local JUnit** test class named *ExampleUnitTest.kt*.

## Observed

#### Error

> Unresolved reference: test

#### Implementation

*ExampleUnitTest.kt*

```
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext
import com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat
```

Comment: Are you using this in an instrumeted test (`androidTest/`) or a unit test (`test/`)? [You seem to have the right package](https://androidx.tech/packages/androidx.test.core.app/#applicationprovider), but perhaps your Gradle dependency directive does not match where the test class resides.

Comment: @CommonsWare, this is under the 'src/test' directory for JUnit testing.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I fixed the first issue with the solution I posted. However, now when I try to retrieve the **app** context, using `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` I receive an error _java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation._. This is using the libraries `import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry` and `import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext`.

Comment: AFAIK, `ApplicationProvider` is for instrumented tests, at least at the moment. I think there's a plan to unify these things with Mockito-based mocks for unit tests as part of Project Nitrogen, but I don't think that's ready yet.

Comment: What about `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()`? I've read this should be used to access the **app** context within a JUnit test [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52932361/2253682).

Comment: @CommonsWare, I've sent a [note](https://twitter.com/AdamSHurwitz/status/1160703815609225216) to '@AndroidDev' via Twitter regarding the documentation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Solution

This appears to be an issue documented in the [Android Testing Codelab sample app](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing).

Within the Codelab sample *build.gradle* this is referred to as a known issue.

```
// Once https://issuetracker.google.com/127986458 is fixed this can be testImplementation
implementation "androidx.test:core:$androidXTestCoreVersion"
```

I refactored my app's dependency to `testImplementation` instead of `androidTestImplementation`.

```
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.2.0'
testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.44'
```

**Note** - The Google documentation [Set up project for AndroidX Test](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project#gradle-dependencies) should be updated to reflect this issue as it currently instructs the developer to use `androidTestImplementation`. I have filed a documentation issue to resolve this.