# Android: Unresolved reference when using junit 4.13

Tags: android, gradle, junit

After updating junit version to 4.13 in gradle dependencies, classes and annotations like `Assert`, `@Test`, etc. under the junit package are displayed as red when used in my code. Lint check says:

```
Unresolved reference: <any junit class>
```

However, when I build and run my tests, it will build and run just fine.

I have tried:

- restarting Android Studio
- Invalidate caches and restart
- Clean and rebuild project
- added `testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"`

What works is downgrading junit to 4.12. How to get rid of this lint error, without downgrading version?

**Update:**

- When I check `ALT + ENTER` options and select `Inspection 'Unresolved reference, in wrong test scope' options` > `Suppress 'IncorrectScope' for file <name of file>`, it gets rid of these lint errors for that particular file. I still like to solve this problem without using Suppress though.
- According to this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140375151), it looks like this bug is not fixed yet. For now I'm downgrading to 4.12.
- Removing both espresso and runner from dependencies also fixes the problem.

Comment: which error do you mean?

Comment: May be related to this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140375151

Comment: Btw. this has nothing to do with the linked issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add the following to your build.gradle (App) file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "junit:junit:$junit_version"
}

dependencies {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first of all check your `external dependencies`
In my case I found double `jUnit` versions which is

```
Junit 4.12
Junit 4.13
```

And the older version is come with `androidx.test`
The solution is

```
1. exclude dependencies
```

or

```
2. remove `androidx.test`
```

or

```
3. add conflict startegy
```

Comment: I tried removing robolectric which I believe is using junit 4.12. Then clean and rebuild project and invalidate cache/restart. It does not fix the problem. Removing both espresso and runner from dependencies actually fix it though.

Comment: I used `exclude group: 'junit' module: 'junit` on suspected dependencies but didn't work. I can't also find any reference about how to remove `androidx.test`. Perhaps you can elaborate more on this or show your code.

Comment: have you ever try {exclude group: 'androidx.test'}

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from @VaheGharibyan's idea about duplicate junit versions, I discovered that the following code also fixes the problem.

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute module('junit:junit:4.12') with module('junit:junit:4.13')
        }
    }
```